# MPDF img tag error

Tags: php, html, pdf, mpdf

I have a problem with the mpdf library.

When I insert a img tag the library I received error 500.

This is my code:

```
<?php


  $tabla = $this->load->view("prueba",$data , true);
  $this->load->library('mpdf');

  //size
  $mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8','Letter',0,0,10.1,10.1,32,29,13.2,13.2);
  $mpdf->showImageErrors = true;


  $stylesheet = file_get_contents('assets/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');
  $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);

  $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div class="cabecera"> <img src="assets/img/asd.png"></div>');

  $mpdf-> WriteHTML ($tabla,2);

  $mpdf-> SetHTMLFooter('<div class="footer"> <span> some text!</span></div>');
  $mpdf->Output('files/daniel.pdf','F');

  $this->response("True", 200);
?>
```

If I do that even without the tag IMG everything works fine.

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

with mpdf I use base64 and it works well. Like:

```
<img alt="logo" width="298" height="108" src="data:image/png;base64,{base64 of the image}>" />
```

To get convert a picture in base64 do:

```
base64 filename.png
```

Comment: Not work, I tray with this.
<img alt="Icono de un libro" width="16" height="16" src="data:image/png;base64,iV
BORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAABGdBTUEAAK/INwWK6QAAABl0RVh0U29mdHd
hcmUAQWRvYmUgSW1hZ2VSZWFkeXHJZTwAAAHjSURBVDjLdZO/alVBEMZ/5+TemxAbFUUskqAoSOJNp4KC
4AsoPoGFIHY+gA+jiJXaKIiChbETtBYLUbSMRf6Aydndmfks9kRjvHdhGVh2fvN9uzONJK7fe7Ai6algA
3FZCAmQqEF/dnihpK1v7x7dPw0woF64Izg3Xl5s1n9uIe0lQYUFCtjc+sVuEqHBKfpVAXB1vLzQXFtdYP
HkGFUCoahVo1Y/fnie+bkBV27c5R8A0pHxyhKvPn5hY2MHRQAQeyokFGJze4cuZfav3gLNYDTg7Pklzpw
4ijtIQYRwFx6BhdjtCk+erU0CCPfg+/o2o3ZI13WUlLGo58....." />

Comment: also I tried with this:
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$data_base = base64_encode($data)
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div class="cabecera"> <img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$data_base'"></div>');